# EditText with InputType password issue from Swipe Keypad

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, swipe

In my application i am pragmatically creating an user login screen with 2 Edit Texts for username and password. and for password Edit Text i am setting the InputType with the following code snippet.

pswdEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD | TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

but my problem is user selects Swipe Keyboard in the device settings and opened the app and trying to enter the text by swiping. if user swipes for password text input is taking the input and showing suggestions without considering the above code snippet which is not expected (Not happening facebook app).

So can any one help me to solve this issue.

any help to solve this issue will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is more bent towards the developers of Swype!

Comment: Yeah!. Talk to developer of Swipe Keypad. You can Post on their Forum http://forum.swype.com/